# Can't upload images to magento products

Tags: php, javascript, image, magento, upload

I have been troubleshooting why my product images just won't upload/show in the admin panel of magento. I have tried all the fixes on the web but can't seem to solve the issue. I can browse, find the file, click upload, I even get the loading status showing the % of the file being uploaded. After it has, what seems like, finished uploading, a remove button appears next to where the image should be, but the actual images doesn't show up.

I have updated the prototype.php

I have tried this: http://blog.magentoconnect.us/image-upload-problemissue-magento-1-6/comment-page-1/#comment-98275

and this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/219072/P15/

and I installed the extension image uploader without javascript to no avail.

I have tried just about everything I can think of. Not really sure why this happened as everything was working fine a week or so ago. Any help or direction would very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey David, is there any `<img>` tag in the place where the image should be but is empty?  Try inspecting - my guess is that there is one there but the image source it's pointing to is not resolving.  If you find that, perhaps the URL it's pointing at doesn't exist or is not outputting valid image data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because of some extension you installed. I had the same issue, but after removing the extension it worked.

Comment: Yeah, I have been trying to disable extensions and see if that is the issue. So far no luck. This is really mind boggling.

Comment: check this out http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/7009/P30/

Comment: Yup, it was indeed an extension. A shipping agent we use called Bongo had installed their extension without telling us and man was it buggy! Thanks fro the help!

Comment: You're most welcome, please do upvote

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of flash player and check it out..